# python script fails in terminal via 'import psutil'

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple script to check the battery time on my laptop (the built in one on xubuntu seems somewhat inaccurate), the code runs fine in a python terminal but when I run it without starting in the python terminal I get an error related to 'import psutil'.
the script is

I'm very inexperienced with python and haven't been able to find anything helpful online.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6.7
import psutil
import time
a=psutil.sensors_battery()
b=str(a)
c=b[b.rfind(start)+len(start):b.rfind(end)]
d=int(c)/3600
print(d)
time.sleep(130)
exit()
```

what I expected is the value c divided by 3600 to be printed on the terminal, display for a while and then exit.  instead i get

```
Desktop$ python battery.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battery.py", line 2, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

i also tried running through the menu options when i right click the script and select python3.6, where a terminal flashes and closes immediatly (to quickly to read any of the print in it).
i've also changed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6.7
```

each has the same result
thank you for any advice
david

Comment: Seems you may have multiple installations of python and are using different ones. The typical shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. How are you opening the "python terminal" and executing your script?

Comment: I do have 2.x.x, 3.6.x, and 3.7.x.  When I use the terminal it's simply python3 I haven't noticed whether that opens 3.6 or 3.7 but I did try python3 in the header with the same result.  The only one I didn't specify at all in the header was 2.xx because it won't import psutil from terminal so i figure it's boot worth trying

Comment: I just got home an checked, when I use the python terminal it is the 3.6.7 version.

Comment: Ok, so I rewrote the script in IDLE for 3.6, saved it, tweaked the header it saved and now it will execute as expected when I choose 'run with python 3.6' from the right click menu.  So that's a success!! however I still get the same failure with psutil if I try running it from the terminal: "python ./battery1.py".  So... success and fail all in one I suppose.

Comment: Ok, so I rewrote the script in IDLE for 3.6, saved it, tweaked the header it saved and now it will execute as expected when I choose 'run with python 3.6' from the right click menu.  So that's a success!! however I still get the same failure with psutil if I try running it from the terminal: "python ./battery1.py".  So... success and fail all in one I suppose.  I believe the only difference was in the header {I don't know how to make this appear in the code format, there is no button for it on the side now.  and it didn't come out properly when I used the button

Comment: anyhow}        #!bin/env python3   is the header that works for running it from the menu, although I commented out a few lines that the IDLE inserted when it was saved.  depending on whether or not I can figure out how to get this to run and output to a file at periodic intervals it could be problem solved, however I'm only familiar with doing that sort of thing in bash and crontab so it will be a new adventure!

Comment: So sounds like you have it figured it out then? If you need to, you can also specify the exact path to the python installation you want to use in your shebang. Kind of defeats the portability aspect though. Or execute with the python you want to use from the command line: `/home/david/anaconda3/bin/python scripy.py` for instance.

Comment: I'm not totally sure saying I figured it out is accurate because it still doesn't make sense you me.  As far as I can guess it was omitting /usr from the header.  Yeah getting it to run doesn't look too difficult, I was looking at some of the scheduling features python offers.